# Django - Serving files from media directory

Tags: python, django

I've deployed a new website to my staging and production servers but for some reason the images in the media directory are displaying 404 errors. The path to the image is correct and the image is located at that path:

```
<img src="/media/projects/hair/2012/test-1/13221803.jpg" alt="Slide 1" width="570" height="270" style="">

ls -la ~/.virtualenvs/website/project/media/projects/hair/2012/test-1
total 144
drwxr-x--- 2 username username   4096 Aug 27 16:43 .
drwxr-x--- 3 username username   4096 Aug 27 16:43 ..
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username username 131719 Aug 27 16:43 13221803.jpg
```

settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Am I having problems because the image file is nested within other directories? Files are being served from the static directory just fine, any ideas?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: did you run manage.py collectstatic?

Answer (score 4):

Does your urls.py have this target?

```
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
            (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
                    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}))
```

Comment: it would be better performing to have the webserver serve static content instead of django.

Comment: Check this URL out [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). If you specify the STATIC_URL, you can point apache or nginx to serve the static files.